# How do you control what is visible in a property grid at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have a property grid displaying a list, for example of a class `Person`

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class Person
{
    public bool ShowHidden { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //[Browsable(false)]
    public string Hidden { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Person({0})", Name);
    }
}
```

The question is how do I control the `Browsable()` attribute at runtime such that when `ShowHidden = false` the `Hidden` line (highlighted yellow below) is omitted.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
PropertyDescriptor descriptor=
  TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.GetType())["DataType"];
BrowsableAttribute attrib= 
  (BrowsableAttribute)descriptor.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)]; 
FieldInfo isBrow = 
  attrib.GetType().GetField("browsable",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
isBrow.SetValue(attrib,false);
```

Just replace `DataType` with your property name.
Note, all properties must have the attribute being changed (in this case, Browsable). If one of the properties is missing the attribute, **all** of the class properties get the new attribute setting.

Code taken from here: [Exploring the Behaviour of Property Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/48015/Exploring-the-Behaviour-of-Property-Grid).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have not made it to work yet. I can't figure out what is the best placement for this snippet. I have it in a property setter, but I see not effect on my grid.

Comment: What I expected was to remove only the row for the instance that has `ShowHidden = false`, but it removes the row from all instances. I will accept the answer as it did kinda what I need.

Comment: The code changes the BrowsableAttribute, but I don' t see the change in grid...how can I see changes runtime?

Comment: @FrancescoDS: You should be able to see changes at runtime. Please post a new question if you have issues with this approach. Based on the number of upvotes, I'd assume it worked for others.

Comment: I had to put another line at the bottom of the code to make this work, something like:
descriptor.SetValue(this, attrib); 
I think the componentchange/changing sequence takes effect after the setValueis called on the base object.

Comment: @ja2 The reason it was hiding all your properties is because this only works when all the properties have a Browsable attribute. The source link mentions this issue.