# How to change the Browsable attribute of a field class after its instantiation

Tags: c#, propertygrid, componentmodel

I’m using in my application `PropertyGrid` controls to display the fields of the classes. To define which fields will be displayed I’m using the `Browsable` attribute from `ComponentModel`.
I need to present the same class in two different forms, in the first all the fields must be showed and in the second, only the fields that user choose must be displayed. Is it possible to change the `Browsable` attribute from `true` to `false` after the class instantiation? A sample code would be very useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you control what is visible in a property grid at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673101/how-do-you-control-what-is-visible-in-a-property-grid-at-runtime)

Comment: An attribute is declared for the type of the class and not the instance of a class, so chaning it from true to false would bascially change it for all instances of the type.

Comment: *"A sample code would be very useful"* - sure, but you have to waste a bit of your time first to create [mcve].